# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.google.com

Tags: jquery, html

i'm have trouble try to add link, to one item of the menu, the console give me the following error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.google.com
html elements

```
          <nav class="main-menu">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a class="verde2" href="#sustancia">LA 
                               SUSTANCIA</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="amarillo2" 
                            href="#vitamina">VITAMINAS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.google.com.mx">BLOG</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="azul2" href="#contacto">CONTACTO</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

jquery elements
i'm using jQuery v3.1.0

```
               $('.main-menu li a').on('click', function(e) {
                    console.log("prueba");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var Ancla = $(this).attr('href');
                   //menu whith class sticky
                   if ($('nav').hasClass('sticky-fixed')) {
                       console.log('sticky header');
                    //height sticky menu
                   $('body,html').stop(true, true).animate({
                       scrollTop: $(Ancla).offset().top - 75
                       }, 1000);


              } else {


                  $('body,html').stop(true, true).animate({
                      scrollTop: $(Ancla).offset().top - 97
                      }, 1000);

              }

       });
```

anyone knows how i can solve this?

Comment: You have a typo in your code, nothing else. Replace $(Ancla) by $(this) and it should be solved. In your code, Ancia is not a jQuery object, is a string - it contains the URL.

Comment: but i declare ancla like var, i'm try add this code to resolve the problem but not resolve it    $('.main-menu li').find("a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. It will work if you replace Replace "$(Ancla)" by "$(this)".

Running example:
https://codepen.io/Rechousa/full/KQZxYo/

Running code:

```
    $('.main-menu li a').on('click', function(e) {
      console.log("prueba");
      e.preventDefault();
      var Ancla = $(this).attr('href');
      //menu whith class sticky
      if ($('nav').hasClass('sticky-fixed')) {
        console.log('sticky header');
        //height sticky menu
        $('body,html').stop(true, true).animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 75
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        $('body,html').stop(true, true).animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 97
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
```

#### Edit:

After your feedback, to redirect to Google, you should check if the URL (your Ancla variable) is an external URL.

Given your scenario, checking for the hash sign should be enough. Use this piece of code, by replacing the four first lines in my previous example.

```
    console.log("prueba");
    var Ancla = $(this).attr('href');
    if(Ancla.charAt(0) !== "#") {
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    //menu whith class sticky
```

Comment: But section blog doesn't direction Google yet